# Wp Query outputting a different criteria every 4th iteration

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a CTP called 'Experts' with each post containing an ACF field for the gender. My assignment is to sort the query to have a female every 4th iteration of the loop. The Post type is quite big and has way more males than female (for example 80 males, 20 female). So it will be unlikely that a female will be skipped.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$args = array(
    'post__not_in'      => array(1279), //Hide my admin account
    'post_type'         => 'experts',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'meta_key'          => 'gender',
    'meta_value'        => 'male'
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args); 

if($the_query->have_posts()): 
    while($the_query->have_posts()):
        $the_query->the_post();
        $termsArray = get_the_terms($post->ID,"expertise");
        $termsString = "";
        foreach($termsArray as $term){
            $termsString .= $term->slug.' ';
        }
?>

<?php 
        if($i % 4 == 0){ 
?>

<?php
            $args = array(
                'post__not_in'      => array(1279), //For testing this could still be me
                'post_type'         => 'experts',
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'orderby'           => 'rand',
                'meta_key'          => 'gender',
                'meta_value'        => 'female'
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query($args); 
            if($the_query->have_posts()): 
                while($the_query->have_posts()):
                    $the_query->the_post();
                    $termsArray = get_the_terms($post->ID,"expertise");
                    $termsString = "";
                    foreach($termsArray as $term){
                        $termsString .= $term->slug.' ';
                    }
?>

            <div class="post-item <?php echo $termsString; ?>">
                My female content like <?php the_title(); ?>
            </div>

<?php 
                endwhile; 
                wp_reset_query(); 
            endif; 
?>
<?php 
        } 
?>

        <div class="post-item <?php echo $termsString; ?>">
            My male content like <?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>

<?php 
        $i++; 
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query(); 
endif; 
?>
```

I've tried many methods but it's just becoming a mess. My example here is outputting all the females when the nth iteration is met. It also seems to break the loop for some reason. What would be the proper approach to handle this? Where do I need to look?

Comment: Well for a start you have reused the variable `$the_query` on the second query (females) and therefore destroyed you handle on the (males) resultset, so call them something else like `$the_males` and `$the_females`

Comment: Then run both queries before starting processing the males. Then you have 2 seperate resultsets you can pick rows from as per your 4 males then 1 femaie rule

Comment: Ah yes using '$the_query' is a dumb mistake, thank you for pointing that out. Do you mean making the two queries load all their post in an array? and order them in the 3 male 1 female setup? Or something different?